# steps in using google places api with android app

Tags: android, json, database-connection, google-places-api

Please help me with connecting the google places api with my android app. This app searches for restaurents based on types of food such as indian, chinese, contenetal etc and gives the results of the restaurents which have these facilities and also the details like user reviews, facilities, offers etc. I had been searching for this for a long time, from my experience i have seen using mapviews for this, i am confused whether i can do this without using the mapview. I have found many help for the google map api but there is only very few help for google places api.I am using the json parser also for the first time, so anyone who can help me kindly give a guidance reply. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

you need a mapview to see the map

google places can help you search for restaurants near a location and 
possibly also reviews-- access it with http requests

you'd need to use json objects/ etc to parse the data that you want from the json